# How would you obtain a Pandas Series from a Dataframe without labels?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I've been searching all over this morning and it seems like every search result i've found pertains to situations where the data frame is specifically labelled.

I am dealing with a small data set that is simply made up of a few columns of numbers, none of them being labeled.

I understand that to get a series out of a labeled data frame column, you would usually do

`# Print out brain column as Pandas Series
print(DF['Brain'])`

and to get a dataframe, you would use the double brackets (still not sure why its double brackets either)

`# Print out brain column as Pandas DataFrame
print(DF[['Brain']])`

Having said all that, how would you get a time series from a specific column if none of your columns are labeled? Is there an indexing version in order to get a series? I know that you can slice data frames via indexing, but slicing returns data frames, not series. Thank you :-)

Edit: Doing DF[0] gives me a keyError

Comment: You can use indexing. Just use the index of column you want in place of label.

Comment: Doing print(DF[0]) gives me a keyError

Comment: So what's wrong with labeling the columns?

Comment: I was given an unlabeled dataset for a beginner challenge. Do all data scientists manually label their datasets before working on them?

Comment: Use df[df.columns[0]].

Comment: Much appreciated Vivek!

Comment: I usually label the columns, it's easy `df.columns = ['bar', 'foo', '...']` so why not?

Comment: `df.iloc[:,0]` can work too

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna get into the habit of labeling. And @MaartenFabré df.iloc[:,0] returns a data frame of the column, not a series. But Vivek's solution looks good.